# Angular test execution seem to be going in infinite loop and crashing the karma browser

Tags: javascript, jasmine, angular6, karma-runner

I am testing this function which is suppose to delete an `EmbeddedViewRef` from a `ViewContainerRef`.

```
  deleteThumbnail(thumbnailContext:ThumbnailContext){
    console.log("delete thumbnail  clicked with context ",thumbnailContext);
    let wasConfirmed = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete the attachment?");
    if(wasConfirmed) {

      console.log("deleting index ", thumbnailContext.index);
      this.thumbnailContainerRef.remove(thumbnailContext.index);
      return false; /*returning false cancels the click and thus cancels further navigation and prevents the browser from going to the page specified (in this case #).*/
    }
  }
```

The following is the test case. It uploads 3 files (the handleFileSelect method will create the embedded views) and then calls the `deleteThumbnail` method to delete them from the view

```
fit('should delete the correct image if multiple images are present and the user deletes a thumbnail', (done) => {
    let newPracticeQuestionComponent = component;
    //expect(newPracticeQuestionComponent.currentImageAttachmentCount).toBe(0);
    expect(newPracticeQuestionComponent.thumbnailContainerRef.length).toBe(0);
    let imageThumbnailDiv1 = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css("#thumbnail-1"));
    let imageThumbnailImg1 = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#img-1'));
    let imageThumbnailClose1 = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#close-button-1'));

    let imageThumbnailDiv2 = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css("#thumbnail-2"));
    let imageThumbnailImg2 = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#img-2'));
    let imageThumbnailClose2 = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#close-button-2'));

    let imageThumbnailDiv3 = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css("#thumbnail-3"));
    let imageThumbnailImg3 = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#img-3'));
    let imageThumbnailClose3 = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#close-button-3'));
    expect(imageThumbnailDiv1).toBeFalsy();
    expect(imageThumbnailImg1).toBeFalsy();
    expect(imageThumbnailClose1).toBeFalsy();

    expect(imageThumbnailDiv2).toBeFalsy();
    expect(imageThumbnailImg2).toBeFalsy();
    expect(imageThumbnailClose2).toBeFalsy();

    expect(imageThumbnailDiv3).toBeFalsy();
    expect(imageThumbnailImg3).toBeFalsy();
    expect(imageThumbnailClose3).toBeFalsy();

    let file1 = new File(["foo1"], "foo1.txt",{type: "image/png"});
    let file2 = new File(["foo2"], "foo2.txt",{type: "image/png"});
    let file3 = new File(["foo3"], "foo3.txt",{type: "image/png"});
    let fileSelectControl = (fixture.debugElement.query(By.css("#question-file-upload"))).nativeElement as HTMLInputElement;
    let reader1= newPracticeQuestionComponent.handleFileSelect(fileSelectControl,[file1]);
    let reader2 = newPracticeQuestionComponent.handleFileSelect(fileSelectControl,[file2]);
    let reader3 = newPracticeQuestionComponent.handleFileSelect(fileSelectControl,[file3]);
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log("in timeout");

      fixture.detectChanges();//without this, the view will not be updated with model
      //expect(newPracticeQuestionComponent.currentImageAttachmentCount).toBe(1);
      expect(newPracticeQuestionComponent.thumbnailContainerRef.length).toBe(3);
      let imageThumbnailDiv11 = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css("#thumbnail-1"));
      let imageThumbnailImg12= fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#img-1'));
      let imageThumbnailClose13 = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#close-button-1'));

      let imageThumbnailDiv21 = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css("#thumbnail-2"));
      let imageThumbnailImg22= fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#img-2'));
      let imageThumbnailClose23 = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#close-button-2'));

      let imageThumbnailDiv31 = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css("#thumbnail-3"));
      let imageThumbnailImg32= fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#img-3'));
      let imageThumbnailClose33 = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#close-button-3'));

      expect(imageThumbnailDiv11).toBeTruthy();
      expect(imageThumbnailImg12).toBeTruthy();
      expect(imageThumbnailClose13).toBeTruthy();
      expect(imageThumbnailDiv21).toBeTruthy();
      expect(imageThumbnailImg22).toBeTruthy();
      expect(imageThumbnailClose23).toBeTruthy();
      expect(imageThumbnailDiv31).toBeTruthy();
      expect(imageThumbnailImg32).toBeTruthy();
      expect(imageThumbnailClose33).toBeTruthy();

      //delete 2nd thumbnail first
      let thumbnailViewRef2:EmbeddedViewRef<ThumbnailContext> = newPracticeQuestionComponent.thumbnailContainerRef.get(1) as EmbeddedViewRef<ThumbnailContext>;
      console.log("will delete 2nd thumbnail with context ",thumbnailViewRef2);

      newPracticeQuestionComponent.deleteThumbnail(thumbnailViewRef2.context);
      console.log("continuing deleting other images. Ref ",newPracticeQuestionComponent.thumbnailContainerRef);
      expect(newPracticeQuestionComponent.thumbnailContainerRef.length).toBe(2);
      console.log("even further.");
      let imageThumbnailDiv211 = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css("#thumbnail-2"));
      let imageThumbnailImg222 = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#img-2'));
      let imageThumbnailClose233 = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#close-button-2'));
      console.log("here now ",imageThumbnailDiv211);
      console.log("here now ",imageThumbnailImg222);
      console.log("here now ",imageThumbnailClose233);


      expect(imageThumbnailDiv211).toBeFalsy();
      expect(imageThumbnailImg222).toBeFalsy();
      expect(imageThumbnailClose233).toBeFalsy();

      //as 2nd was deleted, 3rd now becomes 2nd, 1st stays as 1
      console.log("will delete 1st thumbnail with context ");
      let thumbnailViewRef1:EmbeddedViewRef<ThumbnailContext> = newPracticeQuestionComponent.thumbnailContainerRef.get(0) as EmbeddedViewRef<ThumbnailContext>;
      console.log("repeat will delete 1st thumbnail with context ",thumbnailViewRef1);
      newPracticeQuestionComponent.deleteThumbnail(thumbnailViewRef1.context);
      expect(newPracticeQuestionComponent.thumbnailContainerRef.length).toBe(1);

      let imageThumbnailDiv111 = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css("#thumbnail-1"));
      let imageThumbnailImg122 = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#img-1'));
      let imageThumbnailClose133 = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#close-button-1'));


      expect(imageThumbnailDiv111).toBeFalsy();
      expect(imageThumbnailImg122).toBeFalsy();
      expect(imageThumbnailClose133).toBeFalsy();

      //delete the last thumbnail

      let thumbnailViewRef3:EmbeddedViewRef<ThumbnailContext> = newPracticeQuestionComponent.thumbnailContainerRef.get(0) as EmbeddedViewRef<ThumbnailContext>;
      console.log("will delete 3rd thumbnail with context ",thumbnailViewRef3);
      newPracticeQuestionComponent.deleteThumbnail(thumbnailViewRef3.context);
      expect(newPracticeQuestionComponent.thumbnailContainerRef.length).toBe(0);

      let imageThumbnailDiv311 = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css("#thumbnail-3"));
      let imageThumbnailImg322 = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#img-3'));
      let imageThumbnailClose333 = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#close-button-3'));


      expect(imageThumbnailDiv311).toBeFalsy();
      expect(imageThumbnailImg322).toBeFalsy();
      expect(imageThumbnailClose333).toBeFalsy();

      //console.log("before done call")
      done();//without done, jasmine will finish this test spec without checking the assertions in the timeout
      //console.log("after timeout call")
    }, 2000);


    //if done is not use, jasmine will just finish the current spec without checking any assertions
    //console.log("It is done")
  });
```

The test execution stops sometime after the first call to `deleteThumnbnail` and after sometime, the browser crashes (see the pic). The test execution reaches the point where the 3rd  `console.log("here now ",imageThumbnailClose233);` print is.

[image]

You'll notice in this pic that the `Thumbnail` ref passed to `deleteThumbnail` has a value but later the value of `index` becomes `undefined`

[image]

I think the `expect(imageThumbnailDiv211).toBeFalsy();` line might be the issue looking closely at the following stack trace

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Angular will update the indexes if you remove an item. You are accessing the items by their index within the list but as soon as you delete the item at index 2, the item at index 3, gets reassigned to index 2.

You can see how this works here: https://next.plnkr.co/edit/aBRRw2q8LlhbTNAo

Comment: Thanks. I need to test this. Interesting there was another issue in the code which when fixed solved my problem. It is intriguing how the code is still working if your explanation is correct.